# Are slice objects mutable in function declaration?

Tags: python, default-value, mutable

After learning about how [default arguments work](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments) in python, I went over all my code to look for potential bugs occuring when using mutable sequences.

Now I have a function whose signature is:

```
def get_measurements(self, shape = slice(None, None, None), 
                     size = slice(None, None, None), 
                     height = slice(None, None, None), 
                     pressure = slice(None, None, None),  
                     LE = slice(None, None, None),                          
                     fname = None)
```

And I'm wondering now, are slice objects mutable? And will this cause a problem in above case with default values?

Comment: Why don't you try assigning to their attributes and find out?

Comment: @jonrsharpe "Program testing can be used to show the presence of bugs, but never to show their absence!" - E.W. Dijkstra

Comment: *"Who cares what Dijkstra said, you just want to know if `slice` objects are mutable"* - me, just now

Comment: If they are that doesn't have to be a problem unless some code in `get_measurements()` actually mutates them.

Answer (score 1):

`slice` objects are not mutable.

```py
>>> s = slice(None)
>>> s
slice(None, None, None)
>>> s.start = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: readonly attribute
>>> s.stop = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: readonly attribute
>>> s.step = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: readonly attribute
```

Comment: Yeah that shows it bugs out on a single cpu, but does the code always compile/interpret that way? Isn't this a compiler specific behaviour that might only work on intel and with cpython?

Comment: I'm not sure what the processor has to do with it, but you're right that this could be different on something other than cpython.

Comment: Well the way cpython is compiled might make it behave differently based on the architecture. - Is there a formal definition in the language specification that this should behave like xyz, or is it by design unspecified?